# AnimationDrawable for animation list with various sized drawables?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an animation list consisting of images of (slightly) differing sizes. And I have an `ImageView` with `layout_width` and `layout_height` set as `wrap_content`. I set the animation list to be the content of my `ImageView` and start the animation as follows:

```
AnimationDrawable my_animation_list = (AnimationDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(
    R.drawable.my_animation_list);

myImageView.setImageDrawable(my_animation_list)
((AnimationDrawable)myImageView.getDrawable()).start();
```

I require and would expect the `ImageView` to adjust its height and width with each frame/image in the animation list. Instead, it looks like the `ImageView` takes the height and width of the first frame in the animation list and then scales all of the frames in the animation list to fit this initial height and width. Anyone know how I can get an `AnimationDrawable` (animation list) consisting of various sized images to work with an `ImageView`, or a work-around even?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did in the end was to create my `AnimationDrawable` from my `animation-list` as before, as follows...

```
// declaration in activity
private AnimationDrawable my_animation_list;

// load animation list in onCreate() method of activity or elsewhere
my_animation_list = (AnimationDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(
    R.drawable.my_animation_list);
```

... However, instead of assigning this `AnimationDrawable` to my `ImageView` and then starting it (as in my question), what I now do is to manually assign a frame in the animation list to my `ImageView`, as follows...

```
myImageView.setImageDrawable(my_animation_list.getFrame(myCurrentFrameIndex));
myCurrentFrameIndex++;
```

... And I use a `Handler` to send/receive/process successive `Message` instances to update the frame displayed, determining the duration of each frame as follows:

```
my_animation_list.getDuration(myCurrentFrameIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most fun to do, but you could wrap your bitmaps in [InsetDrawables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/InsetDrawable.html) to make them the same size. It is probably easier to fix the bitmaps them selves. I haven't looked at the code for AnimationDrawable, so there may be better ways...